# PRO C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I've started reading this book lately as trying to move from C++ to C# and saw a lot of references to Windows 8.

I would like to know if the information in the book is still valid and fully working on a Windows 10.

Comment: try out some of the examples and see for yourself ..

Comment: Yes, it is, also Win 7 and Win Server and anywhere else the .NET runtime is supported. And the same language (C#) can be used for tiny ARM devices (.NET Micro), mobile development (Xamarin) and who knows where else (although that's where differences will show up)

Comment: @StenPetrov perhaps you should make this a real answer.

Comment: Deepster, are you expecting someone on this site to go through the entire book and ensure for you that the information is up-to-date and correct? If not then you should probably rewrite your question to be more specific. If so, then this is not the place for that kind of question

Comment: @StenPetrov, I wouldn't say that so loud, I'd guess that by "Windows 8 references" the OP talks about Windows Store apps, and that ain't supported in Windows 7. (BTW: I've read parts of that book)

Comment: How you deploy your code is a separate concern IMO. Here's the ToC for that book https://www.apress.com/9781430242338 Basics (classes, encapsulation, language features), Advanced (LINQ, multithreading, reflection...) and High-Level (WCF, WF, WPF, ASP...) - no mention of anything specific about Windows Store (I haven't read it tho)

Comment: there's a basic confusion here between .net 4.5 and windows 8 (store apps) which is understandable  for someone learning it. I think its valid, but couldve been stated better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the information in this book is still valid, and working on Windows 10.

I recently referenced this book while developing applications using C# 5.0, and .NET 4.5, on Windows 8. After upgrading to Windows 10, I can report that everything compiles, and run as expected. Moreover, most topics in this book won't be obsolete by C# 6.0, or .NET 4.6.

Comment: Won't be obsolete, however, compiling for Windows 8 kills all the new features available in Windows 10...

Comment: What do you mean by compiling for Windows 8? You mean compiling for .NET Framework 4.5?

Comment: @tchau.dev No he means writing windows universal apps (Windows app store) targeting windows 8. Not Desktop apps.

Answer (score 2):

Theres several points here. One is .NET 4.5 - that runs virtually the same on Windows 10. Secondly is WinRT and Universal Windows Applications. That uses a system based COM api callable from C#/C++/JavaScript and is not tied to the installed .NET version. Those are your Windows Store Apps / UWPs (Universal Windows Applications) and there are additional APIs added in Windows 10 over Windows 8.